# WebBrowser1DocumentComplete and WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

The following code gives me several errors two of which are:

- [Error] Unit1.pas(28): Undeclared identifier:
  'WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2'
- [Error] Unit1.pas(34): Undeclared    identifier:
  'WebBrowser1DocumentComplete'

I'm wondering if they aren't declared in the 'uses' section.
Does anyone have any idea why it won't compile.
I got the code from Delphi Help.

Also the 'message box' or the 'beep' for completion doesn't appear.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, StdCtrls, MSHTML, activex;

type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
private
    { Private declarations }
public
    { Public declarations }
end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;
    CurDispatch: IDispatch; {save the interface globally }

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
    if CurDispatch = nil then
    CurDispatch := pDisp; { save for comparison }
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
if (pDisp = CurDispatch) then
    begin
        Beep; {the document is loaded, not just a frame }
        showmessage('download complete');
        CurDispatch := nil; {clear the global variable }
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    WebBrowser1.Navigate('www.google.com');
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that you did not declare the methods.

```
type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    // missing declarations
    procedure WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
    procedure WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
private
    { Private declarations }
public
    { Public declarations }
end;
```

Seems that you just copy'paste the methods from somewhere else :o)

---

### Manual assign Event Handler

For testing purpose I have a simple form with a single `TWebBrowser` component and I have written 2 methods `WebBrowser1DocumentComplete` and `HandmadeDocumentComplete`.

The form code look like this

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

type
  TForm1 = class( TForm )
    WebBrowser1 : TWebBrowser;
    procedure WebBrowser1DocumentComplete( ASender : TObject; const pDisp : IDispatch; const URL : OleVariant );
    procedure HandmadeDocumentComplete( ASender : TObject; const pDisp : IDispatch; const URL : OleVariant );
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1 : TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.HandmadeDocumentComplete( ASender : TObject; const pDisp : IDispatch; const URL : OleVariant );
begin
  // Do something
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete( ASender : TObject; const pDisp : IDispatch; const URL : OleVariant );
begin
  // Do something
end;

end.
```

Now have a look at the ObjectInspector for `WebBrowser1`

[image: ObjectInspector]

Every **published** method that matches the event handler property will be shown inside the combo box and can be selected.

Or you can assign the method by code

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate( Sender : TObject );
begin
  // WebBrowser1.OnDocumentComplete := WebBrowser1DocumentComplete;
  WebBrowser1.OnDocumentComplete := HandmadeDocumentComplete;
end;
```

Comment: Have a look at http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa052802b.htm how to assign the methods with the ObjectInspector :o)

Comment: It all works now. Thanks everybody. Can you link components manually, or do you always have to double click in the 'Events' section?

Comment: Sure you can link them manually, but it is all easier with that double click and code magic. Just assign that method to the event property

Answer (score 1):

This code is working. Tested under Xe³.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3WdX.png

[image]

Here is the diff between your code & my compiled code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRITO.png

[image]

**You have to place `TWebBrowser` visual component to your form.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1CBY.png

[image]

[image]

Comment: OP has browser on his form. He's missing the declarative parts of the methods and because of ignoring the shown error dialogs (*method referenced by... does not exist*) most probably also linkage to the events...

Comment: Fell free to edit my Post Lama :) or post a own answer. I just tried to help.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I'm trying to tell you the problem is something else ;-)

Comment: So OP have to delete the existing events and creating new ones over the visual componenet right?

Comment: I would do so, as it's easiest to describe. IMHO the problem is the OP somehow deleted declarative parts of the methods. Try this; let the IDE generate an event method for you (double-click an event through the Object Inspector). Then delete the method's declaration part and try to build the project. You will get an error message *...method referenced by...does not exist. Remove the reference ?*, say *Yes*. Now in this situation if you suggest to generate the same event methods again, the IDE generates the same named methods, but you will have two of them in implementation part of the code.

Comment: I have to admit that this is the most impressive answer I have ever seen. But as Sir Rufo below has pointed out, I hadn't declared the procedures.